# How verify a ScheduledExecutorService has started?

Tags: java, java-7, scheduledexecutorservice

**Description**

A task A is running, that can last from 2s to 60+s.

While  A is running, I scheduled a ExecutorService that after 10s (delay), would print "running" every 5s (fixed rate).

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduleNotifications = Executors
        .newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
scheduleNotifications.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("A is running");
    }
}, 10, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Once A is done, I wish to print "A is done." **but only if my ScheduledExecutorService task has started**, meaning it printed "running" at least once.

- If A finished before 10s, I do not print anything.
- If A takes more than 10s, I print "running" every 5s and then "done" once A is finished.

How could I do that without using a boolean flag inside the schduled `runnable`. Is there a way to check that my service started?

Comment: This reminds me of a [ProgressMonitor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ProgressMonitor.html) with setMillisToDecideToPopup(10000).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor scheduler = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("A is running");
    }
}, 10, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Thread.sleep(20000);
scheduler.shutdown();
if (scheduler.getCompletedTaskCount() > 0) {
    System.out.println("A is done.");
}
```